# How to extract given array of string with numbers from string in groovy

Tags: grails, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to check if `commit-msg` from git contains particular ticket number with project key of `Jira` using groovy in Jenkins pipeline

```
def string_array = ['CO', 'DEVOPSDESK', 'SEC', 'SRE', 'SRE00IN', 'SRE00EU', 'SRE00US', 'REL']
def string_msg = 'CO-10389, CO-10302 new commit'
```

To extract numbers I am using below logic.

```
findAll( /\d+/ )*.toInteger()
```

Not sure how to extract exact ticket number with project key.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Groovy's find operator - `=~`, combined with a `findAll()` method to extract all matching elements. For that, you could create a pattern that matches `CO-\d+` OR `DEOPSDESK-\d+` OR ..., and so on. You could keep project IDs in a list and then dynamically create a regex pattern.

Consider the following example:

```groovy
def projectKeys = ['CO', 'DEVOPSDESK', 'SEC', 'SRE', 'SRE00IN', 'SRE00EU', 'SRE00US', 'REL']
def commitMessage = 'CO-10389, CO-10302 new commit'

// Generate a pattern "CO-\d+|DEVOPSDEKS-\d+|SEC-\d+|...
def pattern = projectKeys.collect { /${it}-\d+/ }.join("|")

// Uses =~ (find) operator and extracts matching elements
def jiraIds = (commitMessage =~ pattern).findAll()

assert jiraIds == ["CO-10389","CO-10302"]

// Another example
assert ("SEC-1,REL-2001 some text here" =~ pattern).findAll() == ["SEC-1","REL-2001"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex can be assembled a bit simpler:

```
def projectKeys = ['CO', 'DEVOPSDESK', 'SEC', 'SRE', 'SRE00IN', 'SRE00EU', 'SRE00US', 'REL'] 
def commitMessage = 'CO-10389, REL-10302 new commit'

String regex = /(${projectKeys.join('|')})-\d+/

assert ['CO-10389', 'REL-10302'] == (commitMessage =~ regex).findAll()*.first()
```

You can have also another option with finer contol over matching:

```
def res = []
commitMessage.eachMatch( regex ){ res << it[ 0 ] }
assert ['CO-10389', 'REL-10302'] == res
```